# Getting echo output and replacing backslash with forward slash

Tags: command-line

I have a snippet of batch script code that works:

```
echo %tmpfile%
for /R %1 %%G in (*.go) DO (
    echo %%G | findstr /i "test mock" || (
        rem filter out "test" files
        gocyclo "%%G" >> %tmpfile%
    )
)
```

, but with one problem:

it outputs the single backslashes! Even worse, [the program being invoked in the loop](https://github.com/fzipp/gocyclo) doesn't have option to use forward slash instead of backslash!

The code is outputting like this to a file:

```
2 utilities ValArrToPointerArr C:\Users\mwarren\Desktop\apiserver_sdk\utilities\utilities.go:178:1
```

Is there a way to get the output of the program being invoked in the loop, to output forward slashes instead of back slashes, from the script side of things?

Comment: [variable edit replace - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: How would it work in this context? I know you could just do `%f:\=/%`, but to what value would I be setting `f`?

Changing the innermost statement of the for loop to the following: 

`gocyclo "%%G:\=/" >> %tmpfile%` 

especially didn't work. I just got nothing back.

Comment: You have to store the output first, modify it, then write it to the output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a way to output forward slashes instead of back slashes

Yes, using [Variable Edit/Replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

Use the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo %tmpfile%
for /R %1 %%G in (*.go) DO (
  echo %%G | findstr /i "test mock" || (
    rem filter out "test" files
    gocyclo "%%G" >> output.txt
    rem replace \ with /
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('type output.txt') do (
      set line=%%i
      set newline=!line:\=/!
      echo !newline!>>%tmpfile%
      )
   del /q output
   )
)
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Del - Delete Files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: In this case, you're writing it to a text file, called `output.txt`, and then deleting that file afterward, right?

Comment: @MikeWarren Indeed, using it as a temporary file, reading it and modifying the lines read ...